# Quote marks appearing in echo sentence

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I'm building a webpage using PHP. I have a table with multiple buttons. I'm building the buttons in a for loop using the following code:

```
        echo "<tr><td><input type='button' value='".$row['Descripcion']."'";
        echo "onclick=EliminarHashTag('".$row['ID']."','";
        echo $row['Descripcion'];
        echo "','Norma','".$Codigo."','".$Organizacion."')> </td></tr>";
```

It all works fine as long as my variables are strings made of single words.. For example, if
it's `$row['Descripcion']="manometros"`, (string without whitespace) the echo outputs the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Manometros" onclick="EliminarHashTag('14','Manometros','norma','k-300','pdvsa')="">
```

but if my variable is made of a string with whitespace `$row['Descripcion']="Criterios Generales"`, the echo outputs quote marks in the whitespace, messing up the javascript function call syntax and hence making the code not work (Criterios" Generales).

```
<input type="button" value="Criterios Generales" onclick="EliminarHashTag('14','Criterios" generales','norma','k-300','pdvsa')="">
```

I read the echo documentation at php.net, but I saw no mention of this issue. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where is the data for $row coming from?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, debugging tools like firebug and chrome developer tools try to correct it to display a valid domtree. Output proper html and everything will be fine.

Comment: Where's the quotation mark immediately after `onclick=` coming from? It's not in your source PHP but is in both outputs.

Comment: LJ_1102's comment is likely correct / the culprit. You should also add a space after the first echo.

Comment: How does `$row['Descripcion']` become `Criterios Generales` in `value='".$row['Descripcion']."'`/`value="Criterios Generales"`, but `Criterios" generales` in `echo $row['Descripcion'];`/`Criterios" generales`? 1st has uppercase `G` and 2nd has lowercase `g`? There is something you are not showing us

Comment: Your onclick has no quotes around it, that would be one issue.

Comment: @LJ_1102 You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Tom you're right, done so.

Comment: @TOM: The data is coming from a query to mysql

Comment: @nnnnnn: i don't know, when i hit "inspect element" in the broswer it seems to complete the double quotes, my php code does not have them

Comment: @Sean: i dont know how it becomes lowercase, when i chech the html afer the php runs it appears as i pasted in the comment

Comment: If you want to see what the PHP outputs use the browser's "View Source" feature rather than "inspect element".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not quote an attribute, the attributes value ends at the first whitespace or the end of the tag.

Add quotes around the onclick...

```
echo " onclick=\"EliminarHashTag('".$row['ID']."','";
      ^^       ^^
```

and

```
echo "','Norma','".$Codigo."','".$Organizacion."')\"> </td></tr>"; 
                                                  ^^
```

Now if any of the values have double quotes they need to be escaped as html entitles. Or you would need to swap the single for double.

Comment: Thanks!!!! adding the quotes around the javascript call fixed the issue, i didnt know that a whitespace ended the attribute value!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid, debugging tools like firebug and chrome developer tools try to correct it to display a proper domtree.

You're not only missing the closing quote on your `onclick` attribute but also break the encapsulation by using the same type of quotes inside your onclick function arguments:

```
 echo '<tr><td><input type="button" value="'.$row['Descripcion'].'"';
 echo 'onclick="EliminarHashTag(\''.$row['ID'].'\',\'';
 echo $row['Descripcion'];
 echo '\',\'Norma\',\''.$Codigo.'\',\''.$Organizacion.'\')"> </td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the quotes with back slashes:

```
    echo "onclick=EliminarHashTag('".$row['ID']."',\"";
    echo $row['Descripcion'];
    echo "\",'Norma','".$Codigo."','".$Organizacion."')> </td></tr>";
```

I changed the `'` before and after your variable to `\"`.